# Add reference to assembly inside Nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I'm writing a C# class library for net461 that is consuming a NuGet package. The package adds two assembly references to my project as these are the ones you normally need. But in this special case, I also need to reference a third assembly inside the package. I can easily do this by pointing to the folder beneath Packages folder, but that will give me a version-dependent hint path that will break next time the consumed package is updated.

How can I avoid this scenario? I cannot seem to find any way in VS2017 to do a "deep" assembly reference into the referenced Nuget package...

I am also the author of the consumed package, so I could expose the third assembly as  as well, but that would pollute the 99% other projects only needing the two first assembly references.

Thanks in advance
Ulrik

Comment: So, if the third assembly is usually not needed, why is it included in your package?

Comment: Because it is part of the runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another nuget package that references your existing nuget package as a dependency. Then add the additional assembly reference in what is basically a wrapper package. Consume that instead.

Or

Create a copy of the nuget package that includes the assembly reference and add a suffix to the package name. Only issue is you will have to publish two packages whenever you change it. Not sure if it will matter when you have projects using each in the same solution as the dlls should match.

Or

Just include the assembly as a reference and pollute the other projects. I don't **think** it will hurt.

Comment: The point is that the package already contains the assembly I need, it just doesn't expose it. So creating a wrapper package will not really help as that wrapper package would have the same problem of referencing the non-exposed assembly from the original package.

Comment: but the assembly exists within the package?

Comment: Yes, it is in the original package. What I need is a way to add a reference to it in my VS2017 C# project, without referencing the unpacked file in the version-dependent subfolder below packages folder.

Comment: I think the only way is if the package includes the reference.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't seem that there is a really good solution to this, but thanks for your help!